# How to do this type of Custom Gallery in android

Tags: android, slider, android-viewpager, custom-component, image-gallery

I want to get the Following output. It contains set of images & it will slide at some definite interval of time Automatically. I Surfed Google & tried [this](http://www.techipost.com/2011/06/15/android-image-slider-with-auto-slide-code/) link. But it will not Match the desired Criteria. Any help is Appreciable.Thnx.

[image]

Comment: You want to use `ViewPager` and ViewPagerIndicator.

Comment: do you know how to create this "....." type of ViewPagerIndicator if you know please help.

Comment: [CirclePagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: Cheers this is xactly what i need. Thnx.